# use custom browserslist on babel config

Tags: babeljs

i have this old babel config file that have

```
....
    "presets": [
        [
          "@babel/env",
          {
            "targets": {
              "browsers": "> 1%, last 2 versions, not dead"
            }
          }
        ],
....
```

could it be updated like this with custom browserlist config?

```
....
    "presets": [
        [
          "@babel/env",
          {
            "targets": {
              "browsers": "@custom-package/browserslist"
            }
          }
        ],
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this just works:

```
{
  "targets": {
     "browsers": "extends @custom-package/browserslist"
  }
}
```